# Kubeflow Pipeline - Storing (passing) TF.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, kubeflow

I am playing around with Kubeflow Pipelines, what I want to achieve is have one step (python function) where I create an `Iterator` (`generator`), from which I want to create a `TF.Dataset`

Connections between Kubeflow steps are only allowed to have primitive-type inputs/outputs, thus I am not able to pass the Iterator or the iterator-initialized-dataset into the next step.

This is overview of the pipeline

```sh
+-------------+   +-------------------+   +------------------------------+
| Data Ingest +---> Create TF.Dataset +---> Consume Tf.Dataset in Model  |
+-------------+   +-------------------+   +------------------------------+
```

Since I can pass around only primitive types, is there any possibility for storing the Iterator-Initialized Dataset?

Data are on Google Storage, the size is big enought to not fit into memory, how would anyone achieve this?

I know this is kind of broad question, but since Kubeflow is pretty new, I cannot find any helpful resources anywhere.

Comment: What happens in your data ingest step? Some preprocessing, I imagine? Did you consider storing your preprocessed data after the first step, and initialising your tf.dataset iterator in the model training step?

Comment: @sdcbr Exactly, the thing is, the preprocessing may change in time, so storing the processed data might be an overkill. I was thinking about doing the preprocessing on the fly in the dataset with map function. The idea of passing iterator around was briliant to me, however only primitive types can be passed between steps. How would you consume TF.Dataset in the model step?

Comment: I think you should store the data in raw format (or up to the point where the preprocessing does no longer change), and merge the steps where you create and consume the dataiterator.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason to split "Create TF.Dataset" and "Consume Tf.Dataset" into two steps?
How about 
1. merge them into one step?
2. share data set through "write Dataset to storage" / "read Dataset from storage"?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing your TF Datasets?

Suggestion: Store TF Datasets in GCS while you creating it. Then Use tf.data.TFRecordDataset to read your data in the next pipeline stage.

The stages in the pipeline have different runtime. So, you can't use any variable from one pipeline stage to another.